# ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres query that returns values for the following. This query returns one data for the id.

```
select h ->> 'dw:address_line_1' as address, h ->> 'dw:city' as city, h -> 'dw:region' -> 'dw:ID' -> 2 -> '#text' as state, h ->'dw:Country_ISO_Code' as country
from testschema.dw_data_job t, json_array_elements(t.addresses::json) h
where t.id = '12345'
and h -> 'dw:address_type' -> 'dw:ID' -> 1 ->> '#text' = 'BUSINESS'
```

Now I want to get BUSINESS address for entire population in the table `dw_data_job`. I changed query to as follows.

```
select h ->> 'dw:address_line_1' as address, h ->> 'dw:city' as city, h -> 'dw:region' -> 'dw:ID' -> 2 -> '#text' as state, h ->'dw:Country_ISO_Code' as country
from testschema.dw_data_job t, testschema.dw_data_demo t1, json_array_elements(t.addresses::json) h
where t.id = t1.id
and h -> 'dw:address_type' -> 'dw:ID' -> 1 ->> '#text' = 'BUSINESS'
```

Now I get **error** as follows:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array
> CONTEXT:  parallel worker
> SQL state: 22023
> ```

The type of column `dw_data_job.addresses` is `text` and data looks like this - when the JSON value is an **array**:

```
[{"dw:address_line_1": "123 Inter Pkwy", "dw:city": "Richardson", "dw:region": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Texas", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "fc77e3a1ab36487f9646d14f7242dd77"}, {"@dw:type": "Country_Region_ID", "#text": "USA-TX"}, {"@dw:type": "ISO_3166-2_Code", "#text": "TX"}]}, "dw:region_subdivision_1": "Dallas", "dw:postal_code": "75081", "dw:Country_ISO_Code": "USA", "dw:address_type": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Business", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "4fae289a7fe541b098ca9448e462ff6b"}, {"@dw:type": "Communication_Usage_Type_ID", "#text": "BUSINESS"}]}, "dw:primary": "1"}, {"dw:address_line_1": "567 South Dr", "dw:city": "Plano", "dw:region": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Texas", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "fc77e3a1ab36487f9646d14f7242dd77"}, {"@dw:type": "Country_Region_ID", "#text": "USA-TX"}, {"@dw:type": "ISO_3166-2_Code", "#text": "TX"}]}, "dw:region_subdivision_1": "Collin", "dw:postal_code": "75024", "dw:Country_ISO_Code": "USA", "dw:address_type": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Home", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "836cf00ef5974ac08b786079866c946f"}, {"@dw:type": "Communication_Usage_Type_ID", "#text": "HOME"}]}, "dw:primary": "1"}, {"dw:address_line_1": "789 North Dr.", "dw:city": "Plano", "dw:region": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Texas", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "fc77e3a1ab36487f9646d14f7242dd77"}, {"@dw:type": "Country_Region_ID", "#text": "USA-TX"}, {"@dw:type": "ISO_3166-2_Code", "#text": "TX"}]}, "dw:region_subdivision_1": "Collin", "dw:postal_code": "75024", "dw:Country_ISO_Code": "USA", "dw:address_type": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Home-Vac", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "836cf00ef5974ac08b786079866c946f"}, {"@dw:type": "Communication_Usage_Type_ID", "#text": "HOME-VAC"}]}, "dw:communication_usage_behavior": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Mailing", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "bea4505497c901ea53792e2628077617"}, {"@dw:type": "Communication_Usage_Behavior_Tenanted_ID", "#text": "MAILING"}]}, "dw:primary": "0"}]
```

Another sample value with a **non-array** (object):

```
{"dw:address_line_1": "123 Local Pkwy", "dw:city": "Cary", "dw:region": {"@dw:Descriptor": "North Carolina", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "1486a0a4a8464c3b9ec482d4038deb99"}, {"@dw:type": "Country_Region_ID", "#text": "USA-NC"}, {"@dw:type": "ISO_3166-2_Code", "#text": "NC"}]}, "dw:region_subdivision_1": "Wake", "dw:postal_code": "27513", "dw:Country_ISO_Code": "USA", "dw:address_type": {"@dw:Descriptor": "Business", "dw:ID": [{"@dw:type": "WID", "#text": "4fae289a7fe541b098ca9448e462ff6b"}, {"@dw:type": "Communication_Usage_Type_ID", "#text": "BUSINESS"}]}, "dw:primary": "1"}
```

The query needs to accommodate both array and non-array json data to  bring back address, city, state and country code for all rows of data for where the nested key `#text` has the value `'BUSINESS'`.

Comment: The error message is telling you that "addresses" doesn't **always** look like that.  You can use `json_typeof(t.addresses::json)` to find the ones that don't.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. The function json_typeof() returns the type of the outermost JSON value as a string. But I want to iterate through each json array element of the t.addresses::json. All addresses are staring with [ and ending with ]. Based on this we always have at least one element per row.

Comment: For the example you show us, json_typeof(t.addresses::json) is certainly not 'string'.  It is 'array'. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=623a371fc873bd72b2e7e9fe6137e652

Comment: "Potgres" would probably be more relaxed, but Postgres is serious about errors. ;)

Comment: Thank you Jeff and Erwin, I am trying to combine a query that extracts BUSINESS address from both array and non array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message tells you (and Jeff pointed out) there is one or more rows in the table `dw_data_job`, where the column `addresses` does not contain a valid JSON array (or `NULL`). A valid JSON literal, yes, or we'd see a different error message raised by the failed cast to `::json`, but not a JSON **array**.

Run this query to identify violating rows:

```sql
SELECT id, addresses
     , jsonb_pretty(addresses::jsonb) AS js_pretty  -- optional
FROM   dw_data_job
WHERE  json_typeof(addresses::json) IS DISTINCT FROM 'array';
```

(Includes NULL values in `addresses`, which would not raise the reported error, but may be a problem, too.)

To just skip rows with invalid data and proceed with your query:

```sql
SELECT h ->> 'dw:address_line_1' AS address
     , h ->> 'dw:city' AS city
     , h #>> '{dw:region,dw:ID,2,#text}' AS state
     , h ->> 'dw:Country_ISO_Code' AS country
     , json_typeof(t.addresses::json)
FROM   testschema.dw_data_job t
JOIN   testschema.dw_data_demo t1 USING (id)
CROSS  JOIN json_array_elements(t.addresses::json) h
WHERE  json_typeof(t.addresses::json) = 'array'
AND    h #>> '{dw:address_type,dw:ID,1,#text}' = 'BUSINESS';
```

I simplified the syntax with the compact operator [**`#>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) for deeply nested values, and return all `text` instead of some `json` (as educated guess).

To include plain objects as well as arrays, you might:

```sql
WITH sel AS (  -- compute json & type
   SELECT t.addresses::json AS a, json_typeof(t.addresses::json) AS js_type
   FROM   testschema.dw_data_job t
   JOIN   testschema.dw_data_demo t1 USING (id)
   )
 , obj AS (  -- unnest arrays and union with plain objects
   SELECT json_array_elements(a) AS h FROM sel WHERE js_type = 'array'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a                           FROM sel WHERE js_type = 'object'
   -- all other types are ignored!
   )
SELECT h ->> 'dw:address_line_1' AS address
     , h ->> 'dw:city' AS city
     , h #>> '{dw:region,dw:ID,2,#text}' AS state
     , h ->> 'dw:Country_ISO_Code' AS country
FROM   obj
WHERE  h #>> '{dw:address_type,dw:ID,1,#text}' = 'BUSINESS';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1cce593d0cde17735bb10fad2fec34a8)*

Comment: Thank you Erwin, now I see it. Given the scenario of both types, non array and array, how do I extract BUSINESS address in a one query? Thank you

Comment: @BalajiUppalapati: Please clarify that in the *question*. Make the objective clear, provide your version of Postgres and sample data to go with it - incl. an row with non-array data.

Comment: I added non array json data to original post.  The query needs to accommodate both array and non array json data that brings back addressine1, city, state and country code for all rows of data for #text BUSINESS

Comment: I have checked json_typeof(t.addresses::json) = 'array' like this. It worked for me